# How do you add code with quotes to a file using batch?

Tags: powershell, email, batch-file, smtp

I am trying to create a batch file that will create a file that will send an email through powershell. It does many things, but email is just a snippet of it. Here is what I have so far:

```js
REM Creates batch file with contents of the powershell script
echo "I need to add the below powershell script" > email.bat
echo "into email.bat with all the quotes included">> email.bat
echo "like what I'm doing now with appending text">> email.bat
REM powershell script to send email.


$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")

if( $Env:SmtpUseCredentials -eq "true" ) {
    $credentials = new-object Net.NetworkCredential("username","password")
    $smtp.Credentials = $credentials
}
$objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$objMailMessage.From = "myemail@gmail.com"
$objMailMessage.To.Add("whereImsendingto@gmail.com")
$objMailMessage.Subject = "Logs for today"
$objMailMessage.Body = "(the logs)"

$smtp.send($objMailMessage)
```

In batch, I have the way to append text to another file down if what I'm adding does not have quotes, but I need to add text that includes quotes to the file.

Comment: Have you tried to escape the characters inside the string e.g. `\"`?

Comment: Dispense with the batch file and write the script in PowerShell, which has a built-in `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply echo whithout quotes and escape possible chars `<>|&` with a caret `^` and double percent signs?
In a (code block) you've to also escape closing parentheses `^)`

```
@Echo off
( Echo:$smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com"^)
  Echo:
  Echo:if( $Env:SmtpUseCredentials -eq "true" ^) {
  Echo:    $credentials = new-object Net.NetworkCredential("username","password"^)
  Echo:    $smtp.Credentials = $credentials
  Echo:}
  Echo:$objMailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
  Echo:$objMailMessage.From = "myemail@gmail.com"
  Echo:$objMailMessage.To.Add("whereImsendingto@gmail.com"^)
  Echo:$objMailMessage.Subject = "Logs for today"
  Echo:$objMailMessage.Body = "(the logs^)"
  Echo:
  Echo:$smtp.send($objMailMessage^)
) > "SomeFile.ps1"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was getting frustrated about trying to work through delimiters or concatenating two variables or a whole host of different issues. I just tried it and it works exactly like it should. Thank you!

Comment: Well, in the Stack Exchange family of sites the preferred way to thank is voting up and/or check marking the answer.

Comment: I have but it said it won't show unless it receives 15 up votes. I just now checkmarked it though.